# Is there a way for LUIS app connect to SQL server

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

How to connect a LUIS app to the SQL server for retrieving the data back to the user? 
Example: In a chatbot application when a user asks a question to bot after `LUIS` understanding the intent how do we retrieve the answer back from the SQL database?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use other services from Azure in order to achieve this. I recommend using:

Luis + Azure Bot deployed on [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions), which connects to [CosmosDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction)

Comment: Why Azure Functions and/or CosmosDB? If this is Q&A, they can use QnA Maker. If there is an existing DB, they can use whatever appropriate API to get it without using Azure Functions. And Cosmos/Azure Storage have packages that can be used to access data from those resources without directly calling the APIs.

Comment: It was a suggestion on how to interact with a DB, there are others ways of course

Comment: thanks horatiu jeflea and billoverton , @billoverton yes we have an existing DB ,could you please elaborate on how  we can make an API call from Aure Luis bot to Database. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which db are you using?

Comment: @billoverton we are using SQL server

Comment: Ah ok, I don't think you're going to have an API out of the box, then. You'd need to figure out how to create one. I did a quick search and it seems like there are a number of ways to do that. From the bot perspective, you just need to make a REST call to that endpoint once it exists.

Comment: thanks billovertion I will work in respective to developing the REST call